# Group by ordered date

Tags: mysql

I have the following simple table:

```
id | patient_id | case_number | created_at
1  | 1          | x           | 2021-02-25 10:57:24
2  | 1          | y           | 2021-02-25 10:59:24
3  | 2          | z           | 2021-02-25 10:57:14
4  | 2          | w           | 2021-02-25 10:57:29
```

I want to get for each `patient_id`, its most recent `case_number`.
Meaning, final result of sql query I want is:

```
patient_id | case_number
1          | y
2          | w
```

This is what I've been trying:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT patient_id, case_number FROM my_table ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS TEMP 
GROUP BY patient_id
```

But this state returns:

```
patient_id | case_number
1          | x
2          | z
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih 8.0.23 is the versuion

Comment: @ T THE R Ok I see, I wrote an answer hope can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mysql version didn't support `Row_number` window function, You can try to use `self join`

```
SELECT t1.patient_id ,t2.case_number
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) latestDate,
           patient_id 
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY patient_id
) t1 INNER JOIN my_table t2 
ON t1.patient_id = t2.patient_id AND t1.latestDate = t2.created_at
```

From your comment, your MySQL version might be supporting `ROW_NUMBER` window function, you can use that to get the number which is the most recent date.

```
SELECT t1.patient_id,t1.case_number
FROM (
    SELECT patient_id,
            case_number,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM my_table
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: "plus one"  for window function solution

Answer (score 1):

Use window function `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINT patient_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(case_number) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) case_number
FROM my_table
```

Comment: "plus one" for window function solution

Answer (score 0):

try this instead but still need to select created_time:
`select distinct patient_id,case_number,time(created_time) from patients  order by time(created_time) desc limit 2;`